# How to call two different microservices using one GUI form?

Tags: json, node.js, sails.js, microservices

I am creating a one application using Microservice architecture. I have to create a one form which will save data into two different independent services. For example, Form will create a profile and upload showcases.

I am modifying a request and response object. Plus I am using http://senecajs.org/. So my application will not work with standard HTTP Request. I am doing so just because I don't have to relay on HTTP only, I can use TCP also.

To define schema for req and res, I am using http://jsonapi.org/. Can some one help with my req object?

Comment: Just make two separate calls?

Comment: Not sure I understand you completely but are you modifying the request and response object to send to two different services eg. sending the request to one service and then modifying the same request to send to another service afterwards? Also, does the upload showcases response require the request from the create profile step or vice versa?